# Will NKDbgPrintfW be compiled to nop in release build?

Tags: debugging, windows-mobile, windows-ce, platform-builder

I know about and have used the macros `DEBUGMSG`, `RETAILMSG`, `ERRORMSG`, that all take a condition parameter. For general formatted debug output, though, I want to use `::NKDbgPrintfW` directly and wonder if someone knows if it compiles to a nop in optimised release builds or if my own macro wrapper around it with `#ifdef DEBUG` is still needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you need the `#ifedf`

Answer (score 1):

I think you still need the `#ifedf` statement.
Isn't this something you can easily test? You can make your optimized build and set the flag to generate the [`COD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms930912.aspx) files and then see how the call was translated.